# What data structure to use for near realtime lookup on large data set?

Tags: data-structures

I have a dataset of 20 million people whose location is known. In near realtime, I want to know if the query I receive is in this set or not, and if it is, the actual location. Essentially, I want a large hash table. Paying for a network round-trip for Redis/Memcached is out of the question, due to the volume (many thousands of queries per second).

Is there a data structure that can provide very fast membership test, and data retrieval? A small amount of error is acceptable.

Some of the locations are more popular than others. For example, "USA, New York, New York" appears much more frequently than "USA, Alaska, Anchorage".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a sorted Array and doing binary searches is another option:

```
val ids: Array[Long] = new Array(30000000)
val values: Array[Int] = new Array(30000000)
var lookups = Map.empty[String, Int]

// populate ids with sorted array read from disk
Source.fromFile("sorted.csv").map(_.split("\t")).zipWithIndex.foreach {
    case (Array(id, value), index) =>
        ids[index] = id.toLong
        values[index] = lookups.get(value) match {
            case Some(valueIndex) => valueIndex
            case None =>
              val valueIndex = values.size + 1
              lookups = lookups.updated(value, valueIndex)
              valueIndex
        }
}

// Flip lookups around: value becomes key, key becomes value
val realLookup = lookups.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, String]) {
    case (memo, (value, index)) => memo.updated(index, value)
}

// Usage:
Source.fromFile("ids.csv").foreach {
    idStr =>
        val id = idStr.toLong
        val index = java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(ids, id)
        if (index < 0) {
            // Unknown -- check javadoc
            println(idStr)
        } else {
            // Known
            println(id + "\t" + realLookup(values(index))
        }
}
```

Comment: This uses the minimal amount of memory: one long and one int per entry. For 50M entries, I consume about 3.5 GiB of RAM. With a HashMap, I consume over 6 GiB and keels my process over. Runtime is excellent and very stable: the 99th percentile is very stable.

Answer (score 1):

"20 million" - "I want a large hash table" - It sounds like you already have your answer. A hash map containing 20 million items will easily fit in the memory used by a single process on a single machine.

- C++: `std::unordered_map<Key, Value>`
- C#: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<Key, Value>`
- Java: `java.util.HashMap<Key, Value>`
- Scala: `HashMap[Key, Value]`

If you tell us what language you're using, we can point you to the exact type for that language.

Additionally - although I think this might be overkill - you could use an auxiliary [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) (rampion's idea - not mine - just including it here for completeness) to potentially speed up membership tests in the case where the given person (key) is *not* in the hash map.

Comment: `std::map` is not backed by a hash table but by a balanced binary search tree. In C++11 you have the hash table backed `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: @EugenConstantinDinca haha wooops - it's been a long day. :)

Comment: My current implementation targets Scala/Java, but anything that can talk to RabbitMQ is fine.

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil Oh - now I see that the person who answered somehow guessing you needed Scala was in fact you. I'm not familiar with RabbitMQ. Scala has a `HashMap` type, as does Java (updated answer). You could use one of those. It should be more space efficient than a tree-based map.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Bloomier filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Bloomier_filters):

> A Bloom filter **[...]** is a space-efficient probabilistic data structure that is used to test whether an element is a member of a set. False positive retrieval results are possible, but false negatives are not; i.e. a query returns either "inside set (may be wrong)" or "definitely not in set". Elements can be added to the set, but not removed (though this can be addressed with a counting filter). The more elements that are added to the set, the larger the probability of false positives.
>
> **[...]**
>
> Chazelle et al. (2004) designed a generalization of Bloom filters that could associate a value with each element that had been inserted, implementing an associative array. Like Bloom filters, these structures achieve a small space overhead by accepting a small probability of false positives. In the case of "Bloomier filters", a false positive is defined as returning a result when the key is not in the map. The map will never return the wrong value for a key that is in the map.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a plain and simple map:

```
// Scala
val locations: Map[String, Geo] = Map.empty
def location(id: String): Option[Geo] = locations.get(id)
```

That costs a lot of memory though.

Answer (score 0):

A [Judy Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_array)

> is a data structure that has high performance, low memory usage and implements an associative array.

Judy arrays apparently compress very well, and are fast.